# Find the telnet-server in CentOS7.2

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, telnet

I use `yum` installed telnet-server in my CentOS-7.2:

```
yum install -y telnet-server
```

The above prints:

```
Downloading packages:
telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                       |  41 kB  00:00:01     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  installing    : 1:telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64                                                                            1/1 
  verificating      : 1:telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64                                                                            1/1 

installed:
  telnet-server.x86_64 1:0.17-64.el7                                                                                              

Completed！
[root@localhost ~]# vim /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
[root@localhost ~]# find / -name telnet
[root@localhost ~]# find / -name telnet-server
```

You see, I searched for `telnet` and `telnet-server`, but did not find it. 
Where the telnet is? How can I find it and its config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telnet-server package installed the telnet daemon (telnetd) at:

```
/usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

The configuration for it can be found in the man pages:

```
man in.telnetd
```

In general, you can list the files that installed by an RPM by querying the RPM database:

```
rpm -ql telnet-server
```

... which in this case would give you an output like:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/telnet.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/system/telnet@.service
/usr/sbin/in.telnetd
/usr/share/man/man5/issue.net.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/in.telnetd.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/telnetd.8.gz
```

Reference:

- https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.4.1708/x86_64/Packages/telnet-server-0.17-64.el7.x86_64.html